# How to enforce an order of primitives (circle, rect,...) in PIXI.Graphics

Tags: graphics, pixi.js

I am trying to draw multiple circles on top of each other (with different radii) using PIXI.Graphics; it looks like this:

```js
declare var PIXI:any;
const particle = new PIXI.Graphics();

particle.beginFill(0xFFFF00).drawCircle(0,0,5).endFill(); //yellow
particle.beginFill(0xFFA500).drawCircle(0,0,3).endFill(); //orange
```

The yellow circle is always drawn on top of the orange

However, after some fiddling around it seems like that the order of both drawing commands does not determine which of both graphics gets rendered in the foreground (more due to the color?!). This might stem from the GPU implementation -> I dont know the details;

Any ideas how to enforce within a graphics the right z order?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what's exactly your problem because for me they do render in the correct order, you can check this fiddle online:

https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/2f5I0uuKBDq1i7HOMUoXh

Orange circle with a smaller radius is drawn on top of the yellow circle with a bigger radius.

Comment: Thanks for setting up the example (didnt knew that pixi has its own 'fiddle' thingy) ;)

Comment: While it seems to work here as expected, it does not for my local code

Comment: What version of PIXI are you using?

Comment: Version 5.0.0 alpha 3. Maybe I did a mistake somewhere but nevertheless I think drawing  two circles within a Graphics object should behave somehow "atomic"

Comment: I might try to re-produce this issue with more recent versions but as the fiddle mentioned above seems to work fine, I assume it must be either the alpha 3 version (which is outdated by now) or some bug in my code.